# href javascript function call auto decoding issue

Tags: javascript, browser

```
<a href="javascript:myfunc('hi%3dhi')"> </a>
```

This passes text hi&hi to myfunc instead of hi%3dhi. Any way to solve this with out calling myfunc from onclick

Comment: If that string comes from user input, you have an XSS hole.

Comment: Demo of this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/GNUNb/

Answer (score 2):

You **need** to properly escape your string.
Specifically, you need to HTML-encode it, then URL-encode it, then Javascript-encode it.

The `%` character should be converted by the URL-escaping step to `%25`.

Answer (score 1):

yes,

```
<a href="javascript: myfunc('hi%253dhi')"> </a>
```

just [**window.encodeURIComponent**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) `'hi%3dhi'`.